# A get() like method for checking for Python attributes

Tags: python, attributes

If I had a dictionary `dict` and I wanted to check for `dict['key']` I could either do so in a `try` block (bleh!) or use the `get()` method, with `False` as a default value.

I'd like to do the same thing for `object.attribute`. That is, I already have object to return `False` if it hasn't been set, but then that gives me errors like

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'attribute'

Answer (score 150, accepted):

A more direct analogue to `dict.get(key, default)` than `hasattr` is `getattr`.

```
val = getattr(obj, 'attr_to_check', default_value)
```

(Where `default_value` is optional, raising an exception on no attribute if not found.)

For your example, you would pass `False`.

Answer (score 21):

Do you mean `hasattr()` perhaps?

```
hasattr(object, "attribute name") #Returns True or False
```

[Python.org doc - Built in functions - hasattr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr)

You can also do this, which is a bit more cluttered and doesn't work for methods.

```
"attribute" in obj.__dict__
```

Answer (score 7):

For checking if a key is in a dictionary you can use `in`: `'key' in dictionary`.

For checking for attributes in object use the `hasattr()` function: `hasattr(obj, 'attribute')`

Comment: Only answer that addresses the fact that both options for checking a dict presented by OP are Bleh!