# For loop with object's attributes in Python

Tags: python, object, for-loop, iteration

I am working with objects in Python and all I wanted was to replace the attribute in a for loop to get the data out of the object. Here is my code:

```
def calculate_something(dictionaryWithObjects):
    for attribute in ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']:
        dataA1, dataA2 = dictionaryWithObjects['Object1'].attribute
        dataB1, dataB2 = dictionaryWithObjects['Object2'].attribute
        dataC1, dataC2 = dictionaryWithObjects['Object3'].attribute
```

So this is more or less what I think I need. I will use the data for calculations afterwards. But it gives an error saying that the object has no attribute called ".attribute". Of course it doesn't, I meant it to replace the 'attr1' in there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at getattr / setattr  (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

Comment: You're looking for `getattr`, `getattr(dictionary['Obj1'], attribute)`

Comment: `.attribute` is not a variable there, so you can not replace that with the real variable `attribute` in your for loop.

Comment: Since you are learning, once you have the `getattr` working, what happens if you remove the `[` `]` from the series of attribute names in the `for`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A get() like method for checking for Python attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355539/a-get-like-method-for-checking-for-python-attributes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to access an instance attribute by its name, you should use [[Python]: **getattr**(*object, name[, default]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), e.g.:

```
dataA1, dataA2 = getattr(dictionaryWithObjects['Object1'], attribute)
```

Comment: does the dictionaryWithObjects.get("Object1",attribute) have same as u answered

Comment: @Roushan: True, but that wasn't part of the question, and I didn't want to overcomplicate the answer.

Comment: @Roushan: Only now I understood what you mean by your 1st comment. I thought it was replacing the `[]` by the `get` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def calculate_something(dictionaryWithObjects):
    for attribute in ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']:
        dataA1, dataA2 = dictionaryWithObjects['Object1'][attribute]
```

Comment: this doen't work because the attribute is not a key.. It's an object. I've tried that in the beggining x)

Comment: Well can you paste the result for dir(dictionaryWithObjects) and dir(dictionaryWithObjects["Object1"]. This actually helps to get you with your loops over your whatever.

Comment: @NoorAliJafri you would generally want to use `vars` instead of `dir`, but why would you, if you can just us `getattr`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was letting her know to use python's cli with dir(yourobject) to have a better picture of the variable. That's it :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`:

```
data=eval('Object1.'+attribute)
```

Comment: Doesn't work (in the question context), but even if it did, it would be one of the ugliest and avoidable ways.

Comment: Because your code snippet doesn't fit in the question context (where there's no "Obj").

Comment: I've changed it, however the point of SO questions is to also solve problems for future users, so it makes no sense to be entirely context specific.